# Android Development - Installation gone wrong?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I followed a tutorial to install Eclipse and the Android development files onto an Ubuntu (Lucid) installation and Iv a feeling things are not quite right.

The tutorial can be found [here](http://linuxconfig.org/get-started-with-android-application-development-using-linux-and-android-sdk).

The problem seems to be that because everything was installed into the /opt folder I am unable to load any of the sample files because of course they are read only, and I'm unsure about how safe it would be to run Eclipse as root.

My thoughts were to remove all of the Android files and start again and set the location in my /home folder somewhere, but I am unable to find any information on actually removing it (Or if this is in fact the best thing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Install the latest java JDK.
2. Within eclipse, install the android ADT plugin http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
3. Download and install the android sdk http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
4. Run the AVD manager (in the android sdk) to install the platform components. (this can be ran from within eclipse)
5. In eclipse, go to preferences/android and set the SDK path.
6. Create an android application!

Good luck!

Comment: I reformatted your answer, revert if you preferred the old style.

Comment: lol thanks...I tried a few times but it kept reverting to what I had.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I didn't realise that I could select the SDK in that way - everything is working as expected now.